# Нарушают ли короткие выражения, помещенные сразу после двоеточия условной конструкции регламент PEP8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, оформление, pep8

Вся суть вопроса заключена в названии.

Приведу пример:

```
if <condition>: break
```

```
if <condition>: continue
```

Является ли такая запись неправильной с точки зрения PEP8? Искал инфу, но не нашёл.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Flake8 считает это антишаблоном (antipattern)](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E701.html)

> PEP 8: E701 multiple statements on one line (colon)

Я бы посоветовал вам использовать IDE, например бесплатную версию Pycharm, которые автоматически проверяют код на соответствие PEP-8 и подчеркивают те участки, которые нарушают PEP-8. Если навести курсор мыши на подчеркивание, то IDE покажет какое именно правило было нарушено.

Именно так я получил сообщение:

> PEP 8: E701 multiple statements on one line (colon)